# Does liip_imagine convert jpeg/jpg/png file to webp? - symfony php 7.4.9

Tags: php, symfony, png, webp, liipimaginebundle

So i want to convert existing images in my project from jpeg/jpg/png to .webp extensions. I have read that using imagine for it https://github.com/liip/LiipImagineBundle/pull/1307, but
it doesn't work, my liip_imagine looks like this:

```
liip_imagine:
    driver: "imagick"
    default_filter_set_settings:
        format: webp
    webp:
        generate: true
        quality: 80
        cache: ~
        data_loader: ~
        post_processors: [ ]
    resolvers:
        profile_photos:
            web_path:
                # use %kernel.project_dir%/web for Symfony prior to 4.0.0
                web_root: "%kernel.project_dir%/web"
                cache_prefix: "cache"
    filter_sets:
        cache: ~
        my_thumbnail:
            quality: 80
            filters:
                thumbnail: { mode: inset }
                post_processors:
                    optipng:
                        strip_all: true
                        level: 3
        my_thumbnail_webp:
            format: webp
            quality: 80
            filters:
                thumbnail: { mode: inset }
                post_processors:
                    optipng:
                        strip_all: true
                        level: 3
```

and then i have this:

```
<picture>
  <source srcset="{{ '/path/to/image.png' | imagine_filter('my_thumbnail_webp') }}" type="image/webp">
  <source srcset="{{ '/path/to/image.png' | imagine_filter('my_thumbnail') }}" type="image/png"> 
  <img src="{{ '/path/to/image.png' | imagine_filter('my_thumbnail') }}">
</picture>
```

but it doesn't work! how can i solve my problem?
on website i still have /path/to/image.png - so it doesn't change anything, i want to have /path/to/image.png.webp
should i convert every img file in my project to webp and upload it again or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there! You missed the `asset` method in your path:

```
<img src="{{ asset('/relative/path/to/image.jpg') | imagine_filter('my_thumb') }}" />
```

So it should be:

```
<picture>
  <source srcset="{{ asset'/path/to/image.png') | imagine_filter('my_thumbnail_webp') }}" type="image/webp">
  <source srcset="{{ asset('/path/to/image.png') | imagine_filter('my_thumbnail') }}" type="image/png"> 
  <img src="{{ asset('/path/to/image.png') | imagine_filter('my_thumbnail') }}">
</picture>
```

Comment: What happens instead?

Comment: it is still setting path to png file

Comment: should it make new file like '/path/to/image.png.webp' or what?

Comment: Yep. See the issue you mentioned in your question. Does your browser support Webp? And does it create a png thumbnail, or does `imagine_filter` doesn't work at all?

Comment: wow, it doesn't work on my browser, but on google chrome it works and it is ... .png.webp why it doesnt work on older browsers?

Comment: Did my answer help you? If so, consider to upvote/accept my answer. If not, please let me know so I can improve my answer!

Comment: hey man! It works good, but locally. On my nginx server i have problem like
"Unable to create path for /path/to/uploaded/image.png ... Get operation failed". Do you know how to fix this? I'm very tired of it i think i tried almost everything.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/1074748/nginx-liip-imagine-unable-to-create-path-for-get-operation-failed-webp-n

Comment: So you unaccepted my answer after you found out you've got another problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to create webp files among png/jpg, add this into liip_imagine.yaml:

```yaml
liip_imagine:
  webp:
    generate: true
```

This does not require webserver changes to work with them

Comment: This is exactly what already is given in the question.